# How to perform indefinite integration of this function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, integral, indefinite

I need to perform the following operations as shown in the image. I need to calculate the value of function H for different inputs(x) using MATLAB.

[image]

I am giving the following command from Symbolic Math Toolbox

```
syms y t x;
f1=(1-exp(-y))/y;
f2=-t+3*int(f1,[0,t]);
f3=exp(f2);
H=int(f3,[0,x]);
```

but the value of 2nd integral i.e. integral in the function H can't be calculated and my output is of the form of

```
H =

int(exp(3*eulergamma - t - 3*ei(-t) + 3*log(t)), t, 0, x)
```

If any of you guys know how to evaluate this or have a different idea about this, please share it with me.

Comment: I already did as you can see my command but I can't get the desired output. In fact, the output that I am getting is same as unsolved last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Directly Finding the Numerical Solution using [`integral`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html):

Since you want to calculate `H` for different values of `x`, so instead of analytical solution, you can go for numerical solution.

**Code:**

```
syms y t;
f1=(1-exp(-y))/y;   f2=-t+3*int(f1,[0,t]);  f3=exp(f2);
H=integral(matlabFunction(f3),0,100)   % Result of integration when x=100
```

**Output:**

```
H =
   37.9044
```

---

### Finding the Approximate Analytical Solution using Monte-Carlo Integration:

It probably is an "[**Elliptic Integral**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)" and cannot be expressed in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). However, you can find an approximate analytical solution using "[**Monte-Carlo Integration**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration)" according to which:

[image: Monte-Carlo Formula]

**where *f(c) = <sup>1</sup>/<sub>n</sub> Σ f(xᵢ)***

**Code:**

```
syms x y t;

f1=(1-exp(-y))/y;   f2=-t+3*int(f1,[0,t]);  f3=exp(f2);
f3a= matlabFunction(f3);       % Converting to function handle

n = 1000;      
t = x*rand(n,1);               % Generating random numbers within the limits (0,x)
MCint(x) = x * mean(f3a(t));   % Integration
H= double(MCint(100))          % Result of integration when x=100
```

**Output:**

```
H =
   35.2900

% Output will be different each time you execute it since it is based
% on generation of random numbers
```

**Drawbacks of this approach:**

1. Solution is not exact but approximated.
2. Greater the value  of `n`, better the result and slower the code execution speed.

---

<sup>Read the documentation of  [**`matlabFunction`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html), [**`integral`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html), [**Random Numbers Within a Specific Range**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/floating-point-numbers-within-specific-range.html), [**`mean`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) and [**`double`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) for further understanding of the code(s).</sup>

Comment: Thank you Sir. Your suggestion totally worked. But as I should have mentioned earlier, I want the value of function H evaluated at random points for which I desire H to be an indefinite solution. Is it anyway possible?

Comment: What you wrote your question is not an indefinite integral. Read [**this**](http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/Teaching/UBC/101Spring98/101integral.html) for simple explanation